# Is there a way to run iis express from within a .Net app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, hostable-web-core

Is there an assembly that I can reference that would allow me to run my own instance of IIS from within my app?

Comment: why would you want to do that.

Comment: IIRC, IIS express is native code and it has lots of DLLs. Are you aware of Cassini and Kayak?

Comment: @Mauricio: Yes, I've seen those, but I'm needing my app to behave in this environment exactly the same way it would in IIS.

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at Hostable Web Core (HWC) - of which IIS Express is a wrapper - here is a [post with some explanation and source code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sukeshak/archive/2007/12/24/iis7-hosted-web-core-custom-service-webcoreservice.aspx), maybe you can modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: This is a good start, however it does not support asp.net 4.0

Comment: It works only with "IIS" and not "IIS Express". IIS Express installation contains HWC dll files, but it didn't work for me.